# Forms of Nelson Siegel formula

Tags: equivalence-relations, finance, economics

Are these two forms of Nelson Siegel formula equivalent?

$s_{m}(\beta )=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\frac{1-e^{\frac{-m}{\tau _{1}}}}{\frac{m}{\tau _{1}}}+\beta _{2}\left ( \frac{1-e^{\frac{-m}{\tau _{1}}}}{\frac{m}{\tau _{1}}}-e^{\frac{-m}{\tau _{1}}} \right)$

$s_{m'}(\beta )=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\frac{1-e^{-m\tau _{1}}}{m\tau _{1}}+\beta _{2}\left ( \frac{1-e^{-m\tau _{1}}}{m{\tau _{1}}}-e^{-m\tau _{1}} \right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those expressions are certainly not equivalent for the same $\tau$ (e.g. consider what happens when $\tau\rightarrow 0^+$). The first kind of formulation is used in the Nelson Siegel [1987 paper](https://cepr.org/sites/default/files/events/1854_NS_1987.pdf). It is possible the second one may be an alternate parametrization.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @MartinN. ofc, no prob